# Django Admin - "Incomplete response received from application"

Tags: python, django, hosting, admin

I've recently started a Django project - When I go to the Admin page I get an "Incomplete Response Received from Application" message.

I only get this error when viewing my project from my A2 hosting domain [www.educate-malawi.com](http://www.educate-malawi.com). You can access the admin page at the bottom right of the home page.

Is this a problem for my host or is it something that I can fix?

I've tried looking for answers to this problem but everything mentions Ruby on Rails - **This is not a ruby on rails project**.

If you need to see any of my code let me know - I can post it.

Comment: do you have more information, perhaps a stack trace of the error?

Comment: It just html - 
<h1>Incomplete Response Received from Application</h1>

Comment: problem solved?

Comment: Yes - See solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is produced when using a Host and a link in your Django project is either not in your urls.py file or is incorrect.

For me specifically my href linked to "www.educate-malawi.com/admin" when urls.py expected "www.educate-malawi.com/admin/"

Just an interesting error for a bad url!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this error in Django hosted on shared hosting space can refer to this answer:

Go to terminal and type `python manage.py runserver`.
You'll see the actual cause of this error. In my case, it was because I was using a python library in `views.py` which I forgot to install on `cpanel`.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps strictly:

1. If you use WhiteNoise, keep in mind that URL management changes, so you must make sure that the paths end with `/`. Example:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

2. If you recently added image saving features with Pillow, you must also manually install it on your production server; or else you will not be able to save the file and consequently you will get an unexpected error from the application:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

3. It is recommended that before going to production you generate the `requirements.txt` file again; because this error occurs due to an error in `urls.py` (step 1) or due to lack of installation of a library in production:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

i just clear browser cookies and refresh page then check problems solve.