# How to fix "Incomplete response received from application"

Tags: python, django

I must be going crazy...

If I have my views.py file with 48 or less lines, when I POST data to it, I see

> Incomplete response received from application

However, If I have 49 lines or more I get a

> NameError, 'request' is not defined

thrown on line 31 and 49, even if line 31/49 is empty.

Could someone please explain what is happening?

Also btw [Django Admin - "Incomplete response received from application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013637/django-admin-incomplete-response-received-from-application) does not answer my question.

*veiws.py:*

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import *
from datetime import datetime
def remove_xss(chat, request):
    return chat
def find_urls(chat, request):
    new_chat = ' '.join([('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(word, word) if ('http://' in word or 'https://' in word) else word) for word in chat.split(' ')])
    return new_chat
def format_chat(chat, username, request):
    chat = remove_xss(chat, request)
    chat = find_urls(chat, request)
    request = request
    return "hi"
def chat_index(request):
    return render(request, 'chatroom.html')
def chat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        chat = request.POST.get('textfield', None)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            u = request.user.username
            f_chat = format_chat(chat, u, request)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('You must be signed in to continue')
        with open('chats.txt', 'a') as chats: 
            chats.write(f_chat)    
    return render(request, 'chatroom.html')
```

*urls.py:* (Working (i think))

```py
from chat import views

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.chat_index),
    path('chat/', views.chat)
]
```

*Full Traceback:* (when there is >=49 lines)

```
Traceback:

File "/home/raveivcs/virtualenv/backend/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/raveivcs/virtualenv/backend/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/raveivcs/virtualenv/backend/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/raveivcs/backend/chat/views.py" in chat
  49.     

File "/home/raveivcs/backend/chat/views.py" in format_chat
  31.     

Exception Type: NameError at /chat/chat/
Exception Value: name 'request' is not defined
```

Comment: Try putting request as the first parameter in all your view functions.

Comment: No dice, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone coming here, all you need to do is look in different files. The error doesn't have to be in the file you think it is in.

Comment: If you solved your own problem it would help if you posted the solution. Or am I missing something?